# Counting squares algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm

I'm writing algorithm which must count squares in this figure:

[image: figure containing squares to count]

In database I have all points with these columns: `x-coordinate`, `y-coordinate`, `toRight`, `toLeft`, `up` and `down`. `toRight`, `toLeft` etc. are booleans and means you can move to that direction from that point or not.

However it's not clear to me how to take advantage of info about direction. What i have now is this code:

```
public function count(array $points)
{ 
    $pointsGroupedByX = array();
    $edges = array();

    foreach ($points as $point) {
        $key = $point->getX();

        if (!in_array($key, array_keys($pointsGroupedByX))) {
            $pointsGroupedByX[$key] = array();
        }

        if (!in_array($point, $pointsGroupedByX[$key])) {
            $pointsGroupedByX[$key][] = $point;
        }
    }

    foreach ($pointsGroupedByX as $group) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($group) - 1; $i++) {
            for ($j = 0; $j < count($group) - 1; $j++) {

                if ($group[$i] === $group[$j + 1] || $group[$i] > $group[$j + 1]) {
                    continue;
                }

                $edge = array($group[$i], $group[$j + 1]);
                $key = $group[$i]->getX();

                if (!in_array($key, array_keys($edges))) {
                    $edges[$key] = array();
                }

                $edges[$key][] = $edge;
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

It first sorts points into groups by `x-coordinate` and second returns multidimensional array with all possible vertical edges from these sorted points.

Idea is to loop trough each group of these edges and check if another group has opposite edge. For example edge `x:0 y:0 - x:0 y:2`, than next group must have `x:2 y:0 - x:2 y:2`, then:

`x:0 y:0 - x:0 y:4` for opposite edge must look 2 groups further: `x:4 y:0 - x:4 y:4`

`x:0 y:0 - x:0 y:6` for opposite edge must look 3 groups further: `x:6 y:0 - x:6 y:6`

and so on.

However it's not clear to me how to write this, and it looks like wrong approach.

What would be better approach for counting squares algorithm? Thanks

**EDIT**:

Following algorithm from vacawama's answer now i have this code (php):

```
$upperLeft = array();
$upperRight = array();
$lowerRight = array();
$lowerLeft = array();
$squares = 0;

foreach ($points as $point) {
    if ($point->getToRight()) {
        if ($point->getDown()) {
            $upperLeft[] = $point;
        }

        if ($point->getUp()) {
            $lowerLeft[] = $point;
        }
    }
    if ($point->getToLeft()) {
        if ($point->getDown()) {
            $upperRight[] = $point;
        }

        if ($point->getUp()) {
            $lowerRight[] = $point;
        }
    }
}

foreach ($upperLeft as $ul) {
    foreach ($upperRight as $ur) {
        if ($ur->getY() !== $ul->getY() || $ur->getX() > $ul->getX()) { // ur is not at same vertical as ul or not to the right of ul
            continue;
        }
        foreach ($lowerLeft as $ll) {
            if ($ll->getX() !== $ul->getX() || $ll->getY() < $ul->getY()) { // ll is not at same horizontal as ul or not bellow ul
                continue;
            }
            if ($ll->getY() - $ul->getY() !== $ur->getX() - $ul->getX()) {
                continue;
            }
            foreach ($lowerRight as $lr) {
                if ($lr->getY() !== $ll->getY()) {
                    continue;
                }
                if ($lr->getX() !== $ur->getX()) {
                    continue;
                }
                $squares++;
            }
        }
    }
}
return $squares;
```

However it returns wrong answer.

There are 17, not 26 points belonging to all 4 lists and somehow this code returns 17 as squares count.

Comment: There should definitely be 26 points in each of your 4 lists.  If not, check your data.  Also, the `>` in this line should be `<`:  `if ($ur->getY() !== $ul->getY() || $ur->getX() > $ul->getX()) {`

Comment: Do your y values increase as you go down (like is commonly done in computer graphics), or do they increase as you go up (as in a mathematical graph)?  I'm assuming +Y is down.

Comment: Your database should have 41 points for that graph, BTW.

Comment: Values increasing when going down and right. Fixed that line and now it returns 42 squares, so closer. My database contains 41 points indeed, but it's not clear to me how you're getting 26 points belonging to each list. In the picture there are 17 points from whom you can move to each direction

Comment: I hand counted 26 points that could be upperLeft points (make sure you include ALL intersections).  I added my solution, in Swift (sorry I don't know PHP).  You do need to change your `<` to `<=` because we want to exclude corners that fall on the same point (can't be UL and UR at the same time).

Comment: I added a picture of the 26 points that qualify as upper left. Because of symmetry, all of the other corners also have 26 points.

Comment: I thought we are talking about points which can be any angle (all directions are ```true```). And actually i found mistakes in my data, now code works. Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the attributes to tell if a point is a valid `upperLeft`, `upperRight`, `lowerLeft`, or `lowerRight` point.

Here is a possible algorithm that uses that information:

1. Create lists of `upperLeft`, `upperRight`, `lowerLeft`, or `lowerRight` points.

   ```
   // Attributes for inclusion:
   // upperLeft  === (toRight && down)
   // upperRight === (toLeft && down)
   // lowerLeft  === (toRight && up)
   // lowerRight === (toLeft && up)

   for pt in points
     if pt.toRight
       if pt.down
         upperLeft.append(pt)
       end
       if pt.up
         lowerLeft.append(pt)
       end
     end
     if pt.toLeft
       if pt.down
         upperRight.append(pt)
       end
       if pt.up
         lowerRight.append(pt)
       end
     end
   end
   ```

   **Notes:**  a) Some points belong to all 4 lists, so don't use `else-if` for any of those comparisons b) Of the 41 points, only 26 belong to each of the lists
2. Now, find the squares by choosing points from the 4 lists.  If you waited until you selected all 4 corners of a potential square, you'd check `26*26*26*26` `(456,976)` squares.  You can speed up the process by rejecting points that don't work immediately.  For instance, once you have an upper left point, you know the upper right point has to have the same vertical (y-value) and your upper right value has to be to the right of the upper left value.  When you pick the lower left point, it should be below the upper left point (same x-value) and it should be the same distance from the upper left point as the upper left point is from the upper right point (because you're looking for squares).  When you pick the lower right point, it should be aligned with the lower left point (same y-value) and with the upper right point (same x-value).

   ```
   squares = 0
   for ul in upperLeft
     for ur in upperRight
       next if ur is not at same vertical and to the right of ul
       for ll in lowerLeft
         next if ll is not at same horizontal and below ul
         next if dist(ul,ll) != dist(ul,ur)  // looking for squares
         for lr in lowerRight
           next if lr not at same vertical as ll
           next if lr not at same horizontal as ur
           squares += 1
         end
       end
     end
   end
   ```

---

Here is my solution, written in Swift:

```
typealias GridPoint = (x: Int, y: Int, left: Bool, right: Bool, up: Bool, down: Bool)

let points: [GridPoint] = [
    (0, 0, false, true, false, true),
    (2, 0, true, true, false, true),
    (4, 0, true, true, false, true),
    (6, 0, true, true, false, true),
    (8, 0, true, false, false, true),
    (0, 2, false, true, true, true),
    (2, 2, true, true, true, true),
    (4, 2, true, true, true, true),
    (6, 2, true, true, true, true),
    (8, 2, true, false, true, true),
    (0, 4, false, true, true, true),
    (2, 4, true, true, true, true),
    (4, 4, true, true, true, true),
    (6, 4, true, true, true, true),
    (8, 4, true, false, true, true),
    (0, 6, false, true, true, true),
    (2, 6, true, true, true, true),
    (4, 6, true, true, true, true),
    (6, 6, true, true, true, true),
    (8, 6, true, false, true, true),
    (0, 8, false, true, true, false),
    (2, 8, true, true, true, false),
    (4, 8, true, true, true, false),
    (6, 8, true, true, true, false),
    (8, 8, true, false, true, false),
    (3, 1, false, true, false, true),
    (4, 1, true, true, true, true),
    (5, 1, true, false, false, true),
    (3, 2, true, true, true, true),
    (5, 2, true, true, true, true),
    (3, 3, false, true, true, false),
    (4, 3, true, true, true, true),
    (5, 3, true, false, true, false),
    (3, 5, false, true, false, true),
    (4, 5, true, true, true, true),
    (5, 5, true, false, false, true),
    (3, 6, true, true, true, true),
    (5, 6, true, true, true, true),
    (3, 7, false, true, true, false),
    (4, 7, true, true, true, true),
    (5, 7, true, false, true, false),

]

var upperLeft  = [GridPoint]()
var upperRight = [GridPoint]()
var lowerLeft  = [GridPoint]()
var lowerRight = [GridPoint]()

for pt in points {
    if pt.right {
        if pt.down {
            upperLeft.append(pt)
        }
        if pt.up {
            lowerLeft.append(pt)
        }
    }
    if pt.left {
        if pt.down {
            upperRight.append(pt)
        }
        if pt.up {
            lowerRight.append(pt)
        }
    }
}

print(upperLeft.count)   // 26
print(upperRight.count)  // 26
print(lowerLeft.count)   // 26
print(lowerRight.count)  // 26

var squares = 0

for ul in upperLeft {
    for ur in upperRight {
        if ul.y != ur.y || ul.x >= ur.x {
            continue
        }
        for ll in lowerLeft {
            if ll.x != ul.x || ll.y <= ul.y || (ll.y - ul.y != ur.x - ul.x) {
                continue
            }
            for lr in lowerRight {
                if lr.x != ur.x || lr.y != ll.y {
                    continue
                }
                squares += 1
            }
        }
    }
}

print(squares)  // 40
```

---

Here are the 26 points that qualify as upper left:

[image: The 26 upperLeft points]

Comment: Did that help?  Did you have any questions?